# Batch file - rename folder within folder but do not know folder name

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Hi hope someone can advise:

I extract a folder using 7-zip to a folder called xyz

Inside xyz it then holds the name of the folder I extracted but this changes based on each extraction so cannot hard code my batch file, this subfolder (call it abc [The extraction only every contains 1 folder]) then abc contains standard folders I need to copy to another location.

The problem I have is that I need to either rename the abc to a known items so I can set my path variable or I need to be able to access it regardless of its name and then copy sub folders out to where I need them

My attempts to copy the contents of abc or rename (move) folder abc have failed any suggestions appropriated, below is what I have already tried

Attempt to copy folder contents
c:\xyz>xcopy c:\xyz*\ c:\newlocation

c:\xyz>xcopy c:\xyz** c:\newlocation

Attempt to rename the abc folder
c:\xyz>dir /o-n move "*" c:\xyz\newname

Thanks
Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename the subfolder of **xyz** with unknown name to a **fixed** name first:

```
for %%g in (xyz) do ren %%g fixed
```